# Reflection on return type to obtain fields and their docstrings?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to determine the list of fields involved in the return type (in this case "string MyName" and "string MyAddress" from class Ob along with their respective docstrings).

I got to the stage of obtaining the return type but anything else I try is either giving me blank values or throwing an exception. Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SampleProf
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sample cl = new Sample();
            Type myClType = cl.GetType();

            MethodInfo[] methodsInfo = myClType.GetMethods();

            List<string> MethodList = new List<string>();

            // Iterate through all methods
            foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodsInfo)
            {
                if (methodInfo.IsPublic && methodInfo.Name.Contains("Get") && !methodInfo.Name.Contains("GetType"))
                {
                    if (methodInfo.ReturnType != typeof(void))
                    {
                        // Do something here?
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

    }

    public class Sample
    {
        public Ob GetMe()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Ob
    {
        /// <summary>My name</summary>
        string MyName;
        /// <summary>My address</summary>
        string MyAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try just printing out `methodInfo.ReturnType.Name`?

Comment: Yes. I do get the name but I want to get the fields inside that class `Ob`.

Comment: So you have a type, and you want to get its properties/fields. Thats your actual question, and its a pretty easy one. Just make sure to use correct bindingflags

Comment: Doc comments are still *comments* above all.  I'd be unpleasantly surprised if the compiler proper even parses them by default, much less sticks them in the metadata.  You'll probably need to use some command-line option (or setting in the IDE) to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are properties or fields?

For properties, it's real easy, just similar to how you've already retrieved the methods.

```
PropertyInfo[] pi = myClType.GetProperties();
```

For Fields, something like this (using a bitwise OR for the BindingFlags parameter):

```
myClType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Comment: Oops -- I see now you've got Ob defined at the bottom of your code.  Hadn't seen that.  Gimme a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `methodInfo.ReturnType.GetFields()`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have obtained an array of `MethodInfo` objects you can proceed to iterate over each element in the array, querying the `MethodInfo.ReturnType` property to determine the type each function returns.

Once you have obtained an instance of `Type` it is very easy to reflect the fields contained within and print their types and names respectively.

I replaced your somewhat cumbersome condition checking with appropriate `BindingFlags` when suitable. You no longer need to check if the method is public neither do you need to check if the method is called *"GetType"*.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Sample sampleInstance = new Sample();
    Type sampleType = sampleInstance.GetType();

    MethodInfo[] sampleMethods = 
        sampleType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

    foreach (MethodInfo method in sampleMethods)
    {
        var methodReturnType = method.ReturnType;

        if (methodReturnType == typeof(void)) 
            break;

        Console.WriteLine(methodReturnType.FullName);

        foreach (FieldInfo field in methodReturnType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}",  field.DeclaringType, field.Name);       
        }
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Down voters please explain. Upvoted for your time and some useful techniques. Thank you.

Comment: No. Its not incorrect. I accepted Cortright's answer only because it was first.